How to Debug Python-to-C++ Calls in NumPy Using VS Code?
I want to trace how Python functions interact with the underlying C/C++ code of a library but am having trouble setting up a proper debugging workflow.
Could someone guide me on:
Setting up a debugger like gdb or lldb with VS Code to trace Python-to-C++ calls.
Building NumPy with debug symbols to enable detailed tracing.
Best practices for identifying which C/C++ functions are called for specific Python operations.
If there are any tools, extensions, or scripts that could help streamline this, I’d love to hear about them!
Thank you in advance for your help!

CProfile tracks all stack traces in python, it won't tell you what numpy calls in C, only which C interface function was called

So, theres no way of tracing the functions back to the C layer?
